# How to sort <g: countrySelect> depending on the language?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I need to sort the fields depending on the language that is selected. In the documentation I can't find any thing about this. http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/countrySelect.html

Comment: I can do with JS in the browser, but i would be nice to do in the view layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard. The tag internally does this to get a list of countries:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.CountryTagLib.ISO3166_3.entrySet().sort { a, b -> a.value.compareTo(b.value) }.collect() { it.key }
```

There's nothing stopping you from doing something similar except using different sort closure.

Comment: that's nice! Thanks dude!